# How create only one plot in for loop - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have loop with plotting like this:

```
sourad = 0.1:0.1:10;
eta = zeros(1,length(sourad));

for pom = 1:length(sourad)
    eta(1,pom) = sqrt(1/sourad(pom));
end
for j = 1:length(eta);
    prom = 1/(eta(j)^2);
    e=[1+i;2;3+i;4;5;6+i;7;8;9;1+i;2;3;4;5]
    for ide=1:size(e)
        if imag(e(ide,1))<0.0001
           plot(prom,(1/real(e(ide,1)))/(eta(j)^2),'o');
           drawnow;
        else
            continue
        end
    end
end
```

And if I run, it will be making a lots of plots with only one point. And I would like to create **only one plot with all these points**.

Comment: use `hold on` outside the loop

Comment: or `hold all` if you want them to plot in different colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hold on` before you plot the second graph in the same plot. Does not matter if outside or inside loop since the operation is quick. A good idea could be to use `hold off` when you are done to not accidently overwrite anything.